# Transaction is not performed although commit at end?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a simple question. When I start a transaction with `BEGIN TRAN` and in the middle I write some statements and at the end is write `COMMIT TRAN`, whats happens if one statement fails? Will the transaction still be committed and I need to check after every statement if `@@ERROR <> 0`? And what happens if I write at the end `ROLLBACK TRAN`? Will the transaction rollbacked also when all statements worked properly? I am a bit confused :/

Comment: If you don't have any `GO` statements in there - it is treated like a statement batch and a failure in any of the statements in the batch will terminate and rollback entire batch.

Comment: Post your code please.  There are a few reasons why a transaction would not commit.

Comment: You can start by reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

If you use COMMIT TRAN your query will be executed only if there are no errors while ROLLBACK TRAN is used to check if the query is working properly or not, it will definitely rollback even if there is no issue with the query.